# What advantages does it have if a password manager locks the DB automatically on locking the computer? Disadvantages of turning it off?

Tags: password-management, password-cracking

When I unlock my PC the password manager (any type) needs the password again to unlock it's DB containing passwords. I was wondering what the benefit is in that, as my computer is locked anyway.

After reading a few questions here I understand that this is to prevent cold boot attacks. Are there any other advantages?

Or restated differently: What are the resulting security risks when one keeps the DB unlocked while locking the pc?

Comment: This paper is a [good read](https://www.ise.io/casestudies/password-manager-hacking/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the key principles in defending systems is reducing the attack surface. Especially when it comes to critical systems like password managers, you want to apply very high security standards and expose them only when necessary. So it makes sense to lock the password manager whenever you do not need it.

Password managers can lock themselves after a certain (usually configurable) amount of time or at certain events. It makes sense to lock your password manager automatically when you lock your screen, as the password manager can be sure, that you do not need it at that moment. Why leave it exposed, if the rightful owner is currently away?

So what are the actual risks? Let's take a look at the two most probable scenarios:

- **Someone is able to unlock your computer** for any reason (weak password or written down password, etc.). Unlocking your computer is all that's needed to access you password manager, if it doesn't lock itself down. Breaking your login equals breaking your password manager. No second line of defense means less security.
- **Someone compromises your system over the network**. Just because no one is sitting in front of your PC doesn't mean no one can interact with it. If your system gets compromised over the network to a point where an attacker can access your desktop session, you are probably in deeper troubles anyway, but there is still no reason to hand the attacker all your credentials on a silver platter. The shorter the duration your password manager is unlocked, the less likely it is for an attacker to get access. There is a small downside to consider though. If the attacker uses a keylogger, he can get your password for the password manager when you log in again, so logging in less often may sound appealing, but in real life it won't really make a difference, once an attacker took over your PC. Sooner or later you will log into the password manager and the keylogger will be waiting for you.

As you can see, remote compromise is less of a concern, since you have lost everything in this scenario anyway. The main issue is someone logging into your machine and having direct access to your password manager. You basically lose the second line of defense the password manager is trying to provide.

Before I forget, you mentioned cold boot attacks. I assume, you don't have to worry about them. Performing a cold boot attack is really difficult and not many actors will go so far to perform them. If you are really such an exposed and high value target, that you have to worry about cold boot attacks, you shouldn't even consider leaving your password manager open even a second longer than necessary!

If disabling automatic locking is a risk worth taking to avoid entering the credentials for your password manager more often, is up to you to decide. I can only recommend to take the safer route, the decision is now yours.

Comment: "Why leave it exposed, if the rightful owner is currently away?" Definitely a relevant thing to check. https://youtu.be/-bpX8YvNg6Y?t=3113